# Getting 'API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG' when trying to login to workbench

Tags: workbench

Unable to login to workbench.Gives API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG

Answer (score 1):

1. First, check on the organization settings. Enterprise, Unlimited and Developer editions has the API enabled by default. Professional Customers can purchase this feature.
2. Check on the profile for the user. Access the profile settings in order to verify that API is enabled as well.

A. Click Setup | Administration Setup | Manage Users | Profiles.

B. Select the profile that you need to check, and under "Administrative Permissions" verify if API Enabled is checked.

Comment: The second doesn't apply to this error. There is a separate disabled for user error.